# What is the Russian equivalent of "your manhood is small"?

Tags: слова

I apologize for this question. In English, you can use terms like "small man" , "tiny man" etc to point to the size of someone's penis - as a method of shaming.

Can you say in Russian : ты маленький  or мелкие to the same effect? Thank you.

Comment: It's so euphemistic... :> As i know, the "manhood" don't mean "penis" exactly in the dictionary... Well, you can say literally "У тебя мужское достоинство маленькое"... if you like sugarbeans... but really this not a so euphemistic, the " мужское достоинство" usually mean "penis"... Or if you are a girl speaking to man - you can say "Твоя мужественность вызывает у меня... (ну, например) - смех "... etc... if he can understand... the context-dependent one...

Comment: @Пилум I actually heard the last one used in banter.

Answer (score 3):

There is an expression *пиписька не выросла*, literally, "(someone's) wiener hasn't grown yet", which means "wet behind the ears, inexperienced, incapable".

> А с квадриками мериться — пока пиписька не выросла, очень уж они вёрткие.

> — Товарищ старшина! У Вас пиписька не выросла делать замечания старшим по званию!

> А она мне сказала, что у окружающих пиписька не выросла с ней спорить.

Comment: ok. But if someone says the words above to me, will that mean the same?

Comment: @Sean: honestly, I've never heard or seen "small man" or "tiny man" used in the sense you're describing. I've only seen "little man" used in the sense of "ordinary person" or "young person". Could you please provide an example of "small man" used in the sense of "man having a small penis"?

Comment: Several times, in informal political discussion, the fairer sex has thrown phrases at me like "you are a tiny man", "you can't please women", "no woman will ever touch you", "you are a small man". This is in English. 

Recently, I was told, by an Ukrainian person of the opposite sex : "У тебя свои мелкие мечты! Как и ты сам!" 

I am 6 feet 2 inches, or 188 cm. So I am wondering if this sentence can mean the same thing...

Comment: @Sean: do you have non-anecdotal examples of this meaning? maybe a link to Google Books or an online forum or something? *мелкий* in this context most probably means "shallow". This is an insult alright, but not of the kind you're thinking about.

Comment: sadly, no. I only have anecdotal examples.

Comment: it also can be elliptical, missing what actually "didn't grew", assuming the context would tell the rest. It can be considered an antagonist of "you got big ones"

Answer (score 1):

There are some euphemisms about small penis:

- *твой дружок* маленький
- *у тебя* маленький
- *твои N сантиметров* where N is exaggeratedly small (like *с твоими 5 сантиметрами ты ее только насмешишь*)

Of course, *твой* can be replaced to appropriate pronouns in each case like *на мои 30 сантиметров никто не жаловался*.

Please note also "*у тебя еще [ничего] не выросло* [to do something]" is a crude form to say "*ты недостаточно хорош*, [to do something]". Although someone could translate this like "*you have too small penis* [to do something]", there is more accent to "you can't" than to physical feature.
For example:
*- [Антон] жениться вздумал? **Женилка** еще не выросла* means that Anton is too young or too infantile to marry and *женилка* is about his ability to marry but not about his penis.